# Selenium Grid node dropping/reconnecting every 30 seconds, Error: "DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version" in the console

Tags: macos, selenium, virtual-machine, selenium-grid

I am trying to write some selenium grid (3.0.1) tests and using VirtualBox Windows VM's to test the framework.  I can connect a hub to a node on the same machine (Mac or Windows, VM or real) with no issues.  I can also connect my Mac to a co-workers windows machine with no drop.  However, when I connect my Mac to a Windows VM (running VirtualBox, if that helps).  the node drops it's connection every 30 seconds or so.  Plus, When I log in to the console, I see this error message on the node: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AESCe.jpg.  Below is a snippet of the logs to see how often the connection/reconnection is happening.  I need to be able to set this up so I can write the tests before I use them in production.  Thanks!

```
13:19:41.978 INFO - Registered a node http://10.0.2.15:5555
13:20:12.001 INFO - Marking the node http://10.0.2.15:5555 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries.
13:21:12.063 INFO - Unregistering the node http://10.0.2.15:5555 because it's been down for 60062 milliseconds
13:21:12.063 WARN - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://10.0.2.15:5555
13:21:12.461 INFO - Registered a node http://10.0.2.15:5555
13:21:42.481 INFO - Marking the node http://10.0.2.15:5555 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
13:22:42.520 INFO - Unregistering the node http://10.0.2.15:5555 because it's been down for 60038 milliseconds
13:22:42.520 WARN - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://10.0.2.15:5555
13:22:42.945 INFO - Registered a node http://10.0.2.15:5555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it usually happens, I research for 2 days, post to SO, and then find an answer an hour later.  It turns out the VirtualBox VM's network adaptor was set to NAT.  Changing it to Bridged fixed the issue.  Go figure.